# Browser accept self-signed certificate

Tags: browser, https, openssl, x509, pkix

I have created a self signed certificate like this

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPIRE=3650

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then

  EXPIRE=$2  

fi

mkdir -p $1
cd $1

openssl genrsa 2048 > $1.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days $EXPIRE -key $1.key > $1.cert
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -text < $1.cert > $1.info

cat $1.cert $1.key > $1.pem
chmod 400 $1.key $1.pem
```

And configured my apache vhost to use this cert.

Now I wonder which file I have to import in a clients storage (chrome or firefox) to tell the browser everything is ok!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I thought this is a corner case!